# How do I make this code work? I am trying to make the jump power of the player in Gmod but I keep getting errors

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

```
local PLAYER = {}

PLAYER.SetJumpPower( 1500 jumpPower )
```

When I input this command "lua_openscript jumphigh.lua", it says ") expected near 'jumpPower'".
I have tried variation of this and to no avail. I am quite new to lua coding.

Comment: `( 1500 jumpPower )` is a syntax error. If you want both to be arguments, separate them with a comma `,`. You probably only want `1500` to be an argument; `jumpPower` will be `nil` in your snippet anyways. Next problem, `PLAYER.SetJumpPower` is `nil` since `PLAYER` is the empty table.

Comment: How would I fix it? In the player_sandbox.lua file it sets PLAYER to {}.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generally wrong. First you need a player that you want to set the jump power for, then you can call :SetJumpPower(1500) on that player. It could look the following

```
Entity(1):SetJumpPower(1500)
```